# Multi-touch mouse gestures in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8 installed as dual boot.

There is a mousepad specific driver in Windows 8 that lets me use multi-touch gestures such as two finger swipe to go back/forward, pinch to zoom in/out, and pivot rotate. The driver/touchpad is made by Alps.

But on Ubuntu 13.10 there is no multi-touch support like those I can use on Windows.

How can I get the same mouse gestures on Windows to work on Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 1):

This was broken in 13.04 and according to https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1172172 will not be fixed.